# Hibernate storing field in two columns in separate tables with annotations

Tags: hibernate, jpa, orm, mapping

I wonder whether `Hibernate` can stores a field into two different columns in two different tables.

Can that be achieved with `Hibernate`? I know it is quite easily with triggers.

Here is my approach;

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "A")
@SecondaryTable(name = "B")
public class A {
   @Id
   @Column(name = "id")
   private int id;

   // This property in both
   @AttributeOverrides({
   @AttributeOverride(column = @Column(name = "something", table = "B"), name = "something"),
   @AttributeOverride(column = @Column(name = "something", nullable = true), name = "something")})
   private int something;
}
```

Regards.

ssedano.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure it can't. I also wonder why you would need such a thing, but you can simply have two fields and always make sure the the second one has the same value as the first one:

```
public void setSomething(int s) {
    this.something = s:
    this.something2 = s:
}
```

Comment: Because they are in fact the same data. I don't want to mess my data model because of a limitation on the ORM. Thanks anyway!